# JQuery not reaching else statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to completely hide a span tag when the visibility is "hidden" by using display: none which works perfectly, only problem is the else statement is not working at all. I mean, it should alert and display: block but it's not at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".compPass").each(function () {

            if ($('.compPass').css("visibility") == "hidden") {
                $('.compPass').css("display", "none");
            } 
            else {
                alert('');
                $('.compPass').css("display", "block");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You'll have to post an example? The visibility isn't changed when you change the display, it's a CSS property all of it's own, so the rest of the code should have no affect on the condition ?

Comment: just to be sure: your browser did not cache an old version of your java script (happened to me when I started with javascript)

Comment: I prefer to use `$('.compPass').is(':visible')`

Answer (score 4):

By referencing `$(".compPass")` inside the .each, you are referencing **all** elements on the page with that class. Use `$(this)` instead to reference the *current* element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".compPass").each(function () {
        if ($(this).css("visibility") == "hidden") {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        } 
        else {
            alert('');
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

You could also replace this with a single function using the function overload of [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value):

```
$(".compPass").css("display", function() {
    return $(this).css("visibility") === "hidden" ? "none" : "block";
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCRxC/) of the css overloaded function.

Comment: `this` usage is correct? This will also change all elements with `.comPass` right?

Comment: No, it will determine the visibility of each element in turn. The original would always use the first visibility property in the sequence of elements and apply that logic to all `compPass` elements

Comment: That is new.. i really thought you needed an event to actually make use of `this`.. Great.. :).. Need to learn a lot more :)

Answer (score 0):

Else statement is not working since, you are not setting the `visible` property as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".compPass").each(function () {
            if ($('.compPass').css("visibility") == "hidden"){                
                $('.compPass').css("display", "none");
            }else{
                $('.compPass').css("display", "block");
                $('.compPass').css("visibility", "visible");
            }
    });
});
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/oyEhEpoT/1/

Like @RGraham suggested, `.comPass` will toggle all html elements with class `.comPass`. If you need to use a particular one, then you should be using like a click function or any event and inside that use :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".comPass", function (e) {
            if ($(this).css("visibility") == "hidden"){                
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            }else{
                $(this).css("display", "block");
                $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
            }
    });
});
```